# AWS API: How to write code that checks whether a file exists in a specific bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using Amazon S3 API (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html)
and I want to write a code that checks whether a certain filename exists in a bucket. I didn't find this info in the API documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The best method to check if an object exists is to call the [headObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property) function. This is what the `waitFor('objectExists', ...)` method uses behind the scenes to check if an object exists.

Answer (score 0):

You want the [Head](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html) operation:

> The HEAD operation retrieves metadata from an object without returning the object itself.

This is the closest thing to a 'contains' operation that fetches the minimum possible for determining object existence.